# c# Unreachable code detected when filtering parameters in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I am new with c# and I've encountered an warning that's saying: *Unreachable code detected*

I have a class where a constructor is built, like seen below:

```
public class FSC
{
    public string cps { get; private set; }
    public Database database;


    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public string Project
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(Type))
            {
                case 2:
                    return "Evo";
                case 1:
                    return "NBT";
                   default: return string.Empty;
            }

        }
    }

    public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
        {
            throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");

            //parameter filtering
            cps = CPS;

        }
    }
}
```

The warning triggers at `cps=CPS;` Maybe it's not a big deal warning but I think it will help me in my understanding. Thank you!

Comment: You are throwing an Exception just before, so the code will never be reached....

Comment: As soon as you throw or return, everything after it in the same code block is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Since each time the following

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS)
```

is `true`, you throw an exception:

```
 throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
```

the assignemt that follows cannot be reached, because when an exception is thrown a program stops abruptly.

That you *probably* need is the following:

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
    }
    cps = CPS;
}
```

This way you throw an exception when `CPS` is null, empty, or whitespace and you don't proceed to the creation of the object.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this exception, you would need to change your constructor to the following code:

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
    }

    //parameter filtering
    cps = CPS;
}
```

**Edit** Please see commented code below why this exception is being thrown

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        // the exception is being thrown here.
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");

        // any code below will not be reached.
        // closing the bracket before the following statement fixes the "unreachable" code issue.
        cps = CPS;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing an exception which will stop execution before you're setting cps. This is causing your issue. You should put the cps = CPS above your throw.

Comment: That's a bad idea, he likely meant, if null, throw exception; if it has value, assign.

Comment: That's good a point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if you throw an `Exception` you cannot continue executing code unless you `try` - `catch` in the calling method (or further up the chain). You can handle further processing e.g. logging at this stage.

Think about what happens when a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. Later code will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This warning message just warn you that the code that appear after the throw operation will never be reached. This is not an error but just a warning, your program will get compiled independently to this warning. This is just a notice for you to be aware that this code will never be proceed.

Answer (score 0):

see your code :

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");

        //parameter filtering
        cps = CPS;

    }
```

when you throw an exception it will get out of the function so the lines after the throw will never run.

Answer (score 0):

This should remove your warning. The reason you have it is because cps will only be assigned if the condition in your if statement is met.

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
    }

     cps = CPS; //parameter filtering
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        //parameter filtering 
        // other process here if any 
        cps = CPS;
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
    }
}
```

or

```
public FSC(string CPS, FSCServerLocator fscLoc)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CPS))
    {
        //parameter filtering 
        throw new Exception("No vin provided at initialization");
    }
    // other process here if any 
    cps = CPS;

}
```